# Why a traceback is not thrown when accessing an element in a dict that does not exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have a place in my code where I made a mistake in the name of the key of a `dict`. It took some time to understand why the code was not running past that place **because a traceback was not thrown**.

The code is below, I put it for completeness, highlighting with `→→→` the place where the issue is:

```
class Alert:

    lock = threading.Lock()
    sent_alerts = {}

    @staticmethod
    def start_alert_listener():
        # load existing alerts to keep persistancy
        try:
            with open("sent_alerts.json") as f:
                json.load(f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # there is no file, never mind - it will be created at some point
            pass
        # start the listener
        log.info("starting alert listener")
        client = paho.mqtt.client.Client()
        client.on_connect = Alert.mqtt_connection_alert
        client.on_message = Alert.alert
        client.connect("mqtt.XXXX", 1883, 60)
        client.loop_forever()

    @staticmethod
    def mqtt_connection_alert(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc:
            log.critical(f"error connecting to MQTT: {rc}")
            sys.exit()
        topic = "monitor/+/state"
        client.subscribe(topic)
        log.info(f"subscribed alert to {topic}")

    @staticmethod
    def alert(client, userdata, msg):
        event = json.loads(msg.payload)
        log.debug(f"received alert: {event}")
→→→     if event['ok']:
            # remove existing sent flag, not thread safe!
            with Alert.lock:
                Alert.sent_alerts.pop(msg['id'], None)
            return
        (...)
```

The log coming from the line just above is

```
2021-01-14 22:03:02,617 [monitor] DEBUG received alert: {'full_target_name': 'ThisAlwaysFails → a failure', 'isOK': False, 'why': 'explicit fail', 'extra': None, 'id': '6507a61c9688199a34cb006b354c8433', 'last': '2021-01-14T22:03:02.612912+01:00', 'last_ko': '2021-01-14T22:03:02.612912+01:00'}
```

This is the `dict` in which I am trying to erroneously access `ok`, which should raise an exception and a traceback. But nothing happens. The code does not further than that as if the error was silently discarded (and the method silently fails).

I tried to put a `raise Exception("wazaa")` between the `log.debug()` and the `if` - same thing, the method fails at that point but an exception is not raised.

**I am at loss about the reason where an exception could not be visible though a traceback?**

---

The `alert()` method is called in a separate thread, if this matters. For completeness I tried the follwong code just to make sure `threading` does not interfere  but no (I do not see a reason why it should)

```
import threading

class Hello:

    @staticmethod
    def a():
        raise Exception("I am an exception")

threading.Thread(target=Hello.a).start()
```

outputs

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/yop/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.3/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 7, in a
    raise Exception("I am an exception")
Exception: I am an exception
```

Comment: **as if the error was silently discarded**, you can put a **print** there to see if this is the case.

Comment: @Countour-Integral: I do not understand. It is not the logging that does not show up, it is the Traceback

Comment: I don't know what `paho` is, but my guess it's executing `client.on_message` inside of a `try`. The `client` object may contain a list of caught errors?

Comment: @WoJ Yes but what happens at `if event['ok']`, I am saying you could put a `print` inside that if and one outside to see if the function is "killed". You could also try `raise`ing your own Exception to see what happens.

Comment: The thing that calls `alert` may catch and supress the exception. Since we don't know what this `on_message` thing is or how its defined to work, its hard to say. If there is no "ok" key in `event` then an exception is raised and likely something is catching it.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I found a duplicate (and flagged my question as such) following your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It appears to call your callback within a `try`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/42f0b13001cb39aee97c2b60a3b4807314dfcb4d/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L3441), then logs that error:

```
try:
    self.on_message(self, self._userdata, message)
except Exception as err:
    self._easy_log(
        MQTT_LOG_ERR, 'Caught exception in on_message: %s', err)
    if not self.suppress_exceptions:
        raise
```

What I can't explain however is why the exception isn't being `raise`d. I can't see why `self.suppress_exceptions` would be true for you since you never set it, but try:

- Manually setting `suppress_exceptions` using `client.suppress_exceptions = False`. This shouldn't be necessary since that appears to be the default, but it's worth a try.
- Checking the log that it apparently maintains. You'll need to refer to the docs though on how to do that, since I've never touched this library before.

Comment: Thanks. I also found a duplicate following that path.